# How to center a label text in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to center a label text in WPF?

```
Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="What?" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Canvas.Top="5"
```

Answer (score 240, accepted):

use the [HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) property.

**Sample**

```
<Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: @Alan can you update your question with the XAML containing that Label, plus a screenshot of how this looks? Because that property should work...

Comment: @Alan In your updated question you are trying to set 'HorizontalAlignment'.Try setting 'HorizontalContentAlignment' as mentioned in my answer above.It will work

Comment: As mentioned by user1920925, this works for labels only when there is a single line of text.  To control the alignment you can use a TextBlock instead of a label and set the TextAlignment attribute to whatever you need.

Comment: WPF 3.5 does not show this property but when you just type it, it works. Thanks.

Comment: HorizontalContentAlignment ... NOT the auto added HorizontalAlignment

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: If you have multiple lines of content, this will align the left edges of each line, then center the whole block. If you want to center each line, use a TextBlock instead, and set `TextAlignment="Center"`.

Comment: For anyone else looking for this in the Properties edit window, it's under Layout, in the expanded 'advanced properties' section

Answer (score 7):

The Control class has HorizontalContentAlignment  and VerticalContentAlignment  properties. These properties determine how a control’s content fills the space within the control.
Set HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment to Center.

Comment: @Alan, You have used HorizontalAlignment in your code. Use HorizontalContentAlignment to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" and!  Width="Auto".

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```